# How can I use AJAX in my MVC 5 project to make a partial view the last child of a target div?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I'm using the Microsoft unobtrusive AJAX in a basic MVC5 project.

If I have a div:

**Index.cshtml**

```
<div class="panel-group" id="mainContent">
</div>
```

and I have this partial view:

**PanelPartial.cshtml**

```
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <p>Hello world!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I know that I can get it to display once by using

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Change content", "UpdateContent","Home", new AjaxOptions {UpdateTargetId = "mainContent"})
```

Which calls this controller:

**HomeController.cs**

```
public ActionResult UpdateContent()
    {
        return PartialView("PanelPartial");
    }
```

and replaces the div content with the partial view.

The AJAX option `InsertionMode = InsertionMode.After` is close to what I want since that inserts the partial after the div, instead of replacing it. That would mean that I could use that multiple times to add as many partials as I want, **outside** of the target div. But how can I do it inside the target div?

Comment: I had the same problem writing a "Load more" button to get the next X rows of a dataset. I wrote custom jQuery code to handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably have to write your own Javascript function to handle this situation and tell your `AjaxOptions` to call this function in the `OnSuccess` event.

```
using (Ajax.BeginForm("Change content",
    "UpdateContent",
    "Home",
    new AjaxOptions()
    {
        OnSuccess = "updateMainContent"
    }))
{
    <!-- ...HTML... -->
}
```

**Javascript (using jQuery):**

```
// The data parameter will be whats returned from your controller action.
// In this case it will be the resulting HTML from your partial view.
function updateMainContent(data) {
    $("#mainContent").append(data);
}
```